# Insertar información en un String en java

Tags: java, array, string

Hola me gustaría añadir información dentro de un `String` mediante un `scanner` pero no se como hacerlo de momento tengo esto del programa:

```
package cas3;

public class pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String apellidos = "serb ventura trif romero";

        String[] array = apellidos.split(" ");

        for(int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
            System.out.println(array[a]+" "+a);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Este ejemplo y lo que preguntas no tiene nada que ver, o es que no te entiendo. Explica mejor lo que quieres conseguir y qué relación tiene con ese código.

Comment: Como podría insertar información dentro del string si es posible. Preguntándole al usuario que escriba un apellido.

Answer (score 3):

Debes importar la clase Scanner después de indicar el paquete:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Luego cuando en un método quieras usar un Scanner debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Declaración e instaciación del objeto de clase Scanner
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// Pides al usuario la información
System.out.print("Introduce el dato: ");
// Leer de teclado una cadena de caracteres
String informacion = sc.nextLine();
```

Hay otras maneras de capturar información desde teclado, pero esa es una de las más básicas.